# Is it possible to track a phones location using Bluetooth (Android & iOS)

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, gps

I'm trying to create a shared tracking service very similar to Find My Friends on iPhone and I notice that it is impossible to find a friend's current location using GPS when you have no 3G or 4G signal. I was wondering if it was possible to find a friend's phone using a Bluetooth connection and sending off a signal within a close proximity in order to find their location. This is obviously a very complicated process but I'm curious to know if this technology exists.

Answer (score 0):

Is it doable? Yes

Is it worth it?  Not in most cases.

Basically you'll have to play around with the underlying bluetooth APIs, create a pairing with another device(all in code) and then transfer the coordinates from one device to another. I would highly recommend using some other alternative.

If it is android specific only, you can try to manipulate the NFC chips. That would be a lot easier in comparison to bluetooth since NFCs don't require pairing. The only downside is that apple only has Passive NFC chips(as opposed to android's Active NFC Chips) and on top of that, apple hasn't made the NFC API open for developers. So this option will not work with ios.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the signal strength also to calculate direction (few articles on google about this) but you will end up with something like near or far, cause the exact location cannot be determined.